# What's an effective offsite backup strategy for a ZFS mirrored pool?

Tags: backup, zfs

I use a ZFS pool consisting of two mirrored disks.  To get offsite backups going, I've purchased two more disks.

My initial plan was to create the offsite backup by attaching a third disk to the mirror, waiting for ZFS to resilver, then detach the drive and carry it offsite.  This works well enough, but I've been surprised that it appears to perform a *full* resilver every time a disk is attached (I'd read, and possibly misunderstood, that each attach would result in an incremental or delta resilver).  This results in backups taking longer than is acceptable.

My requirements are to have an offsite copy of my zpool and all its snapshots that I can rotate daily.  This means the resilvering needs to take at most 24 hours--currently it's close to that, but our plans of growing our pool will push it beyond that timeframe.

How can I keep offsite backups that don't require a full resilvering operation?  Should I be using a different filesystem on my backup drives (e.g. exporting an image rather than having them be part of the ZFS pool)?  Should I have the backups in a separate pool and send new snapshots to it as they are created?

Comment: My current strategy is the multiple pool method, with zfs send and receive to keep snapshots synced up. Would love to hear if you've found an argument against this or a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much tinkering and experimentation I've found a solution, albeit with a fairly large tradeoff.

First off, the options I had to rule out:

- Having a second offsite ZFS server with a mirrored pool wasn't an option due to cost.  Had it been an option this would by far have been the best approach, utilizing ZFS send / receive to ship snapshots to the remote pool.
- Having a second onsite ZFS mirrored pool, which I could remove disks from to take home.  This is more feasible than the first option, but I would need the second pool to always have two disks onsite (or to use two data-copies on a single onsite disk).  At present I have four disks, and no more space for a fifth in the server.  This would be a fair approach but still not ideal.
- Using ZFS attach and detach to rotate the backup disk into and out of the mirrored pool.  This works well, but has to perform a full resilver every time the disk is added.  This takes unacceptably long, and so I couldn't rely on this.

My solution is similar to using `attach` and `detach`, however it uses `online` and `offline`.  This has the advantage of performing a delta resilvering versus a full resilvering, but the drawback that the pool always reports a `DEGRADED` state (the pool always has two disks; the rotating offsite disks are marked `offline` when they are in remote storage and resilver and then come online when they are onsite).

So, a quick recap and overview of my setup:

I have one ZFS server and four identical disks.  ZFS is setup to use a mirrored pool.  Two of the four disks are permanent members of this pool.  The other two disks rotate; one is always in offsite storage, the other is part of the pool to act as a ready-to-go backup.

When it comes time to rotate the backups:

- I wait for a `zfs scrub` to complete to reasonably assure the backup disk is error free
- I `zfs offline` the disk which will be taken remote.  After its offline'd I `hdparm -Y /dev/id` to spin it down.  After a minute I partially remove the disk sled (just enough to ensure its lost power) and then give it another minute before fully pulling the drive to guarantee it has stopped spinning. The disk goes in a static bag and then a protective case and goes offsite.
- I bring in the other offsite disk.  It gets installed in the hotswap tray and spins up.  I use `zfs online` to restore the disk to the pool and kick off a partial resilvering to make it concurrent.

This system guarantees that at any given time I have two `ONLINE` mirror disks and one `OFFLINE` remote disk (which has been scrubbed).  The fourth disk is either being resilvered or online, which has the benefit that in case a running drive fails it's probably the pool will still consistent of two online disks.

It's worked well for the past couple weeks, but I'd still consider this a hackish approach.  I'll follow up if I run into any major issues.

---

**Update:** After running with this for a couple months I've found that in my real-world use the resilvering is taking the same time for either detach/attach and offline/online.  In my testing I don't think I was running a scrub--my hunch is that if a drive is offline for a scrub then it requires a full resilver.

Comment: Will this definitely not work with just three devices instead of four? The [Oracle Solaris ZFS Administration Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gavwg/index.html) states that a mirror pool is faulted "If **all components** of a mirror are removed" [emphasis mine], which would seem to imply that a fourth drive isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: By three devices do you mean two disks that are always in the pool and one that is occasionally offsite, or one disk that's always in the pool and two that rotate offsite?  With the second option I would expect data loss if the pool encounters bad data while there is only one fully online disk (when the 2nd disk is either being rotated or not yet fully resilvered).  My two-cents is to always ensure your mirrored pool has two full-time online disks.

Comment: I meant the second option you mention. With that option, how likely is bad data while only one disk is online? The partial/incremental resilvering should be relatively quick, right? And even if there was bad data, shouldn't you be able to recover from the second drive? Or recover from the third drive, worst case? [Obviously there are scenarios where recovery isn't possible; but that's true even with four drives; or any number actually.]

Comment: I'd stick to always having two online mirrored disks, with a third and fourth used to rotate backups.  Any time that you have just one online disk in a mirror is a time that you're vulnerable--and even with my approach there is the risk that the offsite backup disk could develop integrity issues and not be 100% recoverable (ideally there would be two mirrored disks offsite at any time, so that the integrity of the two could be compared).

Comment: To sum it up, ZFS is all about avoiding a single copy of data (or at least having parity, allowing reconstruction of bad data).  When you have only one online disk or one copy of backup data it is at risk of data loss.

Comment: I agree that more redundancy is generally better, but I'm curious how well ZFS can still work with even more minimal configurations than what you've outlined. Given that everyone advises against using such configurations (instead of offering information about them), I'll probably have to investigate myself. But I suspect ZFS is useful even in the 'degenerate' case of a single-drive zpool (even with no replicas).

Comment: To be clear a single disk pool has no redundancy.  ZFS's #1 feature is data integrity, which requires either multiple copies or parity data.  With a single disk pool (especially with `copies=1`) ZFS has zero ability to repair corrupt data.  At this point it becomes an extremely memory intensive volume manager and filesystem; LVM2 and any other filesystem will provide a much less resource-intensive solution for these features.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20092/discussion-between-kenny-evitt-and-stw).

Comment: You don't have to send/receive to/from remote system, you can send/receive on the same machine to a different pool. Wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: not for **offsite** backups

Answer (score 2):

Why not zfs send your snapshots to a remote ZFS machine?  I use a simple bash script for this:

```bsh
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
# ZFS Snapshot BASH script by Shawn Westerhoff
# Updated 1/14/2014

### DATE VARIABLES
# D = Today's date
# D1 = Yesterday's date
# D# = Today less # days date
Y=$(date -v-1d '+%m-%d-%Y')
D=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)
D1=$(date -v-1d '+%m-%d-%Y')
D10=$(date -v-10d '+%m-%d-%Y')
D20=$(date -v-20d '+%m-%d-%Y')

# Step 1: Make the snapshots

for i in $( zfs list -H -o name ); do
    if [ $i == tier1 ]
    then echo "$i found, skipping"
    else
    zfs snapshot $i@$D
    fi
done

# Step 2: Send the snapshots to backup ZFS sever

    for i in $( zfs list -H -o name ); do
        zfs send -i $i@$D1 $i@$D | ssh -c arcfour root@10.10.10.10 zfs recv $i
    done

# Step 3: Destroy snapshots that are 20 days old

for i in $( zfs list -H -o name ); do
        if [ $i == tier1 ]
        then echo "$i found, skipping"
        else
        zfs destroy $i@$D20
        fi
done
```

Answer (score -2):

I've created [zfs autobackup](https://github.com/psy0rz/zfs_autobackup) to do this and more in a transparent way:
(It only works between two zfs systems, it cant backup to a foreign system).

> ZFS-autobackup tries to be the most reliable and easiest to use tool, while having all the features.
>
> You can either use it as a backup tool, replication tool or snapshot
> tool.
>
> You can select what to backup by setting a custom ZFS property. This
> makes it easy to add/remove specific datasets, or just backup your
> whole pool.
>
> Other settings are just specified on the commandline: Simply setup and
> test your zfs-autobackup command and fix all the issues you might
> encounter. When you're done you can just copy/paste your command to a
> cron or script.
>
> Since its using ZFS commands, you can see what it's actually doing by
> specifying --debug. This also helps a lot if you run into some strange
> problem or error. You can just copy-paste the command that fails and
> play around with it on the commandline. (something I missed in other
> tools)
>
> An important feature thats missing from other tools is a reliable
> --test option: This allows you to see what zfs-autobackup will do and tune your parameters. It will do everything, except make changes to
> your system.

For installation instructions, and downloads please see https://github.com/psy0rz/zfs_autobackup